# AngularJS: Why is .then() not waiting for the promise object to arrive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have created the following angular service for the purpose of making the API calls.

```
(function (module) {
    module.service('APIService',function ($http, $q) {
        console.log("Reached APIService")
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        this.getData = function (requestURL) {
            console.log("Reached APIService @GET", requestURL);
            $http.get(requestURL).success(
                function (data, status) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    console.log("In service",status,data);
                }).error(
                function (data, status) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                    console.log(status);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        this.postData = function (requestURL, requestObj) {
            console.log("Reached APIService @POST", requestURL, requestObj);
            $http.post(requestURL, requestObj).success(
                function (data, status) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    console.log(status);
                }).error(
                function (data, status) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                    console.log(status);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    });
}(angular.module("MainApp")));
```

I have injected it in my two controllers. However, I am facing following issues:

1. When I call it first time in first controller, it works fine and returns the desired result. However, when I call it in second controller as follows:

   ```
       APIService.getData(Config + headerURL).then(function (response) {
           console.log(Config + headerURL);
           console.log("header response from API", response);

       },function(error) {
           console.log("API call for header data failed");
       });
   ```

Since my service returns a promise object, I don't expect the code inside .then() to work before the service data arrives.
 However, it runs before service data arrives (no clue how). The most strange thing is that the response that I get inside .then() is not actually the response from this URL (Config+headerURL), but it is the response that was obtained from a different URL previously called in first Controller using the same APIService service.

Just to inform: the actual response from current URL do arrive at a later stage.

I am aware of asynchronous callings and I think it has something to do in this case, but I guess .then() handles it in Angular. So I am confused what is the issue here. Can anyone shed some light please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the service is a singleton, you only have a single instance of the deferred object.

Once resolved, it will keep being resolved, so the next time you call, getData, it will return immediately.

You could move:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
```

inside both your getData and postData function.

Or you could just return the promise that $http creates.

Comment: Great point..thanks for reminding singleton concept. I should definitely move deferred inside my methods. But I still do not get if the promise is immediately resolved and return, Why and how do I get the valid response from current URL, after a while

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari, as bregnvig said you only have one instance of the deferred object. That means the first time you call `getData()` everything will work as expected, but the second time you call it you get the same promise and that promise has already resolved. When you call `.then()` on a promise that has already resolved it triggers immediately.

Comment: @Duncan: I clearly understood your point. But as I mentioned, I get the new response after some time. That is what is troubling me now. It surely means that the method getData is executed even after sending the previously resolved promise

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari, yes when the second data object arrives you resolve the promise again so the `.then()` will trigger a second time. That probably isn't defined behaviour because you shouldn't be resolving a promise multiple times but it makes perfect sense. Creating a fresh call to `$q.defer()` for each `getData()` call will fix things.

Comment: Thanx u both..hope the thing works. Choosing the answer as the accepted one for reminding singleton !!!

Answer (score 1):

Just try this, You need to `return` to  the http result.

```
this.getData = function (requestURL) {
            console.log("Reached APIService @GET", requestURL);
           return $http.get(requestURL) };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to disable cache explicitly within $http call.

```
$http.get({
  url: requestURL,
  cache: false
})
```

Comment: Your point seems to be valid, But then as I said the desired result do arrive. In fact If I see, console written inside APIService, it prints the current URL. So the current URL is being processed inside the APIService. My main problem is how can the code inside .then() executes without waiting for service.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an *anti-pattern* by creating your own promises when `$http` already returns a promise.

Get rid of `$q` altogether in this service and simply return `$http`

```
this.getData = function (requestURL) {
    console.log("Reached APIService @GET", requestURL);
    return $http.get(requestURL).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
        console.log("In service", status, data);
    }, function () {
        // errror handling here
    });

};
```