# Angular directive function not waiting promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

**The Problem**
In a nutshell, I have a function in my directive that isn't waiting for a promise to resolve before executing.

**Background**
I've created a `selectContacts` directive that consumes a `contactsAPI` service. I've used this same `contactsAPI` service with other controllers in my app (so I know it works), but this is the first time I've tried injecting it into a directive. When my directive controller calls `contactsAPI.getContacts()`, I would expect the `.then()` function to wait for the promise from `contactsAPI.getContacts()` to resolve before executing, however that doesn't seem to be the case. Instead the `.then()` function triggers immediately causing the `contacts` variable within to be assigned an `undefined` value.

Here is my `contactsAPI`:

```
app.service('contactsAPI', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    var contactsAPI = this;
    var contactsAPI.contacts = [];

    contactsAPI.getContacts = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(!contactsAPI.contacts) {
            $http.get('/contacts.json').then(function(resp) {
                if(resp && resp.data) {
                    contactsAPI.contacts = resp.data.contacts;
                    deferred.resolve(contactsAPI.contacts);
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve([]);
                }
            }, function(err) {
                contactsAPI.error = true;
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(contactsAPI.contacts);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);
```

Here is my `selectContacts` directive:

```
app.directive('selectContacts', ['$http', 'modal', 'contactsAPI', function($http, modal, contactsAPI) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/select_contacts.html',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            story: '=',
            token: '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'modal', 'contactsAPI', function($scope, $http, modal, contactsAPI) {
            var contacts;

            contactsAPI.getContacts().then(function(resp){
                contacts = contactsAPI.contacts;
            });
        }]
    }
}]);
```

I've tried a few different approaches to resolving the problem, without success:

1. I tried attaching a watcher to `contactsAPI.contacts` and installing a listener in my directive. I had mixed results with that. Sometimes `contacts` would be defined properly, but at least half of the time it would be `undefined`.
2. I tried moving my `contactsAPI.getContacts()` getter function from my directive into its parent controller, and then injecting the results into my directive's scope. That failed because `contacts` is still `undefined` when the directive is instantiated. That approach seemed like bad practice from the start, but it was worth a shot.
3. I tried a similar approach to #2 above, except that I loaded the contacts into the directive's parent controller and than attached a watcher on the parent controller's `$scope.contacts` and a listener in the directive. That didn't work either and just seemed like bad practice.
4. I've tripled checked that my dependency injection for the directive is right. There were a few posts I came across with similar problems resulting from dependencies being injected incorrectly or out of order.
5. I've also ensured that `contactAPI.getContacts()`'s `deferred` variable is not persisted for the life of `contactsAPI`, which was the source of a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718326/angularjs-why-is-then-not-waiting-for-the-promise-object-to-arrive)

Comment: Are you sure you are not running into the `else` branch? Does the http request actually happen? Did you start debugging it?

Comment: var contactsAPI.contacts = []; <-- What is this? This is impossible, but should throw a syntax error. Try removing that var maybe?

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Sounds like you may be breaking a reference somewhere by overwriting a previous object reference

Comment: In your select contacts directive shouldn't it be contacts=resp;

Comment: Turns out it was an obvious mistake right under my nose. `var contactsAPI.contacts = []` should have been `var contactsAPI.contacts;` since `[]` is truthy.

Comment: I don't understand, that what you wrote is an obvious syntax error. You cant declare variables like that. If you have an object contactsAPI, you can write something like contactsAPI.contats = [] (without var). I am still surprised you are not getting something like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: Good catch. My production code doesn't have the `var` on that line. I put it there on accident when I was simplifying my code to explain the problem, which turned out to be that I was assigning `contactsAPI.contacts = []`, causing my `else` block in `contactsAPI.getContacts` to always run.